# Adobe Flash CS6: Have many instances with the same instance name

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I am making a game in flash, and I am coding in actionscript 2. But I want to have triggers to indicate ground and walls etc.
But i can't give the triggers the same Instance Name. What could i do as a alternative?

Thank You for the help...

Comment: Do you want to have the triggers act in the same way, but have different names?

Comment: I found a way just had 1 movieclip with a instance name and maked the triggers inside of that